# How to Set Opacity (Alpha) for View in Android

Tags: android, button, view, opacity

I have a button as in the following:

```
<Button 
     android:text="Submit" 
     android:id="@+id/Button01" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
```

In my `onCreate()` event, I am calling Button01 like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

View Button01 = this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
Button01.setOnClickListener(this);
```

There is a background in the application, and I want to set an opacity on this submit button. How can I set an opacity for this view? Is it something that I can set on the java side, or can I set in the main.xml file?

On the java side I tried `Button01.mutate().SetAlpha(100)`, but it gave me an error.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I just found your question while having the similar problem with a TextView. I was able to solve it, by extending TextView and overriding `onSetAlpha`. Maybe you could try something similar with your button:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AlphaTextView extends TextView {

  public AlphaTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public AlphaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public AlphaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onSetAlpha(int alpha) {
    setTextColor(getTextColors().withAlpha(alpha));
    setHintTextColor(getHintTextColors().withAlpha(alpha));
    setLinkTextColor(getLinkTextColors().withAlpha(alpha));
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this also helped me. However it's ridiculous that a TextView and an ImageView have different ways to set alpha.

Comment: This helped me too for applying click effect on image view without second resource. Thanx!!

Answer (score 606):

I'm amazed by everyone else's **MUCH** more complicated answers.

### XML

You can very simply define the alpha in the color definition of the button (or any other view) in your xml:

```
android:color="#66FF0000"    // Partially transparent red
```

In the above example, the color would be a partially transparent red.

When defining the color of a view, the format can be either `#RRGGBB` or `#AARRGGBB`, where `AA` is the hex alpha value. `FF` would be fully opaque and `00` would be full transparent.

### Dynamically

If you need to dynamically alter the opacity in your code, use

```
myButton.getBackground().setAlpha(128);  // 50% transparent
```

Where the INT ranges from `0` (fully transparent) to `255` (fully opaque).

Comment: This is still not the solution if you have a compound drawable

Comment: Set half transparent green color of view:
<RelativeLayout android:background="#8700FF00"/>

Comment: View does not have `android:color` attribute.

Comment: @moshersan You can set the color in the android:background property itself!

Comment: What about a three digit value? like Alpha 255?

Comment: @HereticMonk Just use a Decimal to Hex conversion tool to determine what Hex value to use. `255` Dec would be `FF` Hex.

Comment: android:alpha could be another solution from XML.

Comment: @Dheeraj Bhaskar : Not if the view background is an image. Then the answer holds. bacground <> bg color.

Comment: That is incorrect `background` opacity isn't `view` opacity. Not equivalent in many use cases

Answer (score 228):

I guess you may have already found the answer, but if not (and for other developers), you can do it like this:

```
btnMybutton.getBackground().setAlpha(45);
```

Here I have set the opacity to 45. You can basically set it from anything between **0**(fully transparent) to **255** (completely opaque)

Comment: This is only available on API 11+ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)

Comment: @Graeme you have linked to the setAlpha method on the View class, but the post is using the setAlpha on the Drawable class. The getBackground method returns a Drawable. This method is from API Level 1. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setAlpha(int)

Comment: Oh interesting! I didn't see that. Would this mean that the text was fully visible even if the background was set to transparent.

Comment: -1 this doesn't work in my case where my background drawable is a selector.

Comment: this works great but with one side effect: i have many buttons sharing  the same background and they become all transparent! :(

Comment: @Mark you are right, do you know any workaround for this side effect?  I tried to clone the same background (which is a color res) with a different name, but it didn't work..!?

Answer (score 90):

Much more easier from the above.
Default alpha attribute is there for button

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```

The range is between 0 for complete transparent and 1 for complete opacity.

Comment: When I do this, I get a compile error: "**aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed**"

Answer (score 67):

What I would suggest you do is create a custom [ARGB color](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color) in your colors.xml file such as :

```
<resources>
<color name="translucent_black">#80000000</color>
</resources>
```

then set your button background to that color :

```
android:background="@android:color/translucent_black"
```

Another thing you can do if you want to play around with the shape of the button is to create a [Shape drawable resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) where you set up the properties what the button should look like :

file: res/drawable/rounded_corner_box.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#80000000"
        android:endColor="#80FFFFFF"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

Then use that as the button background :

```
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_box"
```

Comment: If you're struggling to covert from 40% opacity to a hex value you can use google search "40% of 255 to hex" gives the hex value for 40%

Answer (score 63):

According to the android docs view alpha is a value between 0 and 1.  So to set it use something like this:

```
View v;
v.setAlpha(.5f);
```

Comment: That's what only worked for me for whole view... I have tried on listview item, which has multiple textviews too. this single line helped to set alpha on view and its children. Thanks @cange1

Comment: Only thing that worked for me as well. I know this is old, but thanks @cange1

Answer (score 19):

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

The above is something that I know...
I think creating a custom button class is the best idea

**API Level 11**
Recently I came across this [android:alpha](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:alpha) xml attribute which takes a value between 0 and 1. The corresponding method is [setAlpha(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29).

Comment: Hi Josnidhin. Thank you for your reply. But it makes the whole button completely transparent. What I am looking is putting some opacity (maybe via alpha value) on the button.

Comment: It's a float, so you can use values BETWEEN 0 and 1, 0.5 for instance.

Comment: @StackOverflowed - i believe ncakmak meant the first solution. setting `@android:color/transparent` as Background will indeed make the view completely transparent. The `@android:alpha` - part seems to be an addendum.

Answer (score 18):

Although `btnMybutton.getBackground().setAlpha(45);` is nice idea, it just apply alpha to background and not the whole view.

If you want apply alpha to view use `btnMybutton.setAlpha(0.30f);` instead. This apply opacity to View. It accepts a value between 0 and 1.

Doc says:

> Sets the opacity of the view. This is a value from 0 to 1, where 0
>   means the view is completely transparent and 1 means the view is
>   completely opaque. If this view overrides onSetAlpha(int) to return
>   true, then this view is responsible for applying the opacity itself.
>   Otherwise, calling this method is equivalent to calling
>   setLayerType(int, android.graphics.Paint) and setting a hardware
>   layer. Note that setting alpha to a translucent value (0 < alpha < 1)
>   may have performance implications. It is generally best to use the
>   alpha property sparingly and transiently, as in the case of fading
>   animations.

Answer (score 13):

For a view you can set opacity by the following.

```
view_name.setAlpha(float_value);
```

The property `view.setAlpha(int)` is deprecated for the API version greater than 11. Henceforth, property like `.setAlpha(0.5f)` is used.

Comment: This is  the correct answer. Just using height to 1dp makes it look thick.

Answer (score 8):

If you use **Kotlin** , it's very easy to set alpha like this

```
imageView.alpha= 0.5F
```

where the value must be a **float number**.

Answer (score 7):

I've run into this problem with ICS/JB because the default buttons for the Holo theme consist of images that are slightly transparent. For a background this is especially noticeable.

**Gingerbread vs. ICS+:**

[image: Gingerbread] [image: ICS]

Copying over all of the drawable states and images for each resolution and making the transparent images solid is a pain, so I've opted for a dirtier solution: wrap the button in a holder that has a white background. Here's a crude XML drawable (ButtonHolder) which does exactly that:

**Your XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              style="@style/Content">
  <RelativeLayout style="@style/ButtonHolder">
      <Button android:id="@+id/myButton"
              style="@style/Button"
              android:text="@string/proceed"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**ButtonHolder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

**styles.xml**

```
.
.
.      
  <style name="ButtonHolder">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/buttonholder</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  </style>
.
.
.
```

However, this results in a white border because the Holo button images include margins to account for the pressed space:

[image: Too much white] [image: Too much white pressed]

So the solution is to give the white background a margin (4dp worked for me) and rounded corners (2dp) to completely hide the white yet make the button solid:

**ButtonHolder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:top="4dp" android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
      <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

The final result looks like this:

[image: No white] [image: No white pressed]

You should target this style for v14+, and tweak or exclude it for Gingerbread/Honeycomb because their native button image sizes are different from ICS and JB's (e.g. this exact style behind a Gingerbread button results in a small bit of white below the button).

Answer (score 6):

For API < 11 for textView color I did the following:

```
int textViewColor = textView.getTextColors().getDefaultColor(); 
textView.setTextColor(Color.argb(128, Color.red(textViewColor), Color.green(textViewColor), Color.blue(textViewColor))); //50% transparent
```

A little cumbersome, but hey, it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know this already has a bunch of answers but I found that for buttons it is just easiest to create your own .xml selectors and set that to the background of said button. That way you can also change it state when pressed or enabled and so on. Here is a quick snippet of one that I use. If you want to add a transparency to any of the colors, add a leading hex value (#XXcccccc). (XX == "alpha of color")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#70c656" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#53933f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#70c656"
                android:endColor="#53933f"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#53933f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```