# Is it possible to set the transparency of a view in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, transparency

I would like to change the transparency of a whole View in Android. How can I do that? The View has a nontransparent background.

Comment: So if it's the main screen you want to be able to see the android home page or you want all the containers less transparent and the background same transparency?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Set Opacity (Alpha) for View in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757/how-to-set-opacity-alpha-for-view-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since API Version 11 it is possible to set the opacity of a view with [`setAlpha()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29).

For older Versions it may be possible with the [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) backport of View property animations.

Answer (score 0):

[`View.setBackgroundDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29). Use a [`ColorDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html) with the appropriate alpha value?

Comment: That is only possible if I use a Color as a background. What if I use a drawable? I could always change the alpha of png that is shown as the background manually but that seems to be a bad solution for some cases.