# Making a button semi-transparent in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Set Opacity (Alpha) for View in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757/how-to-set-opacity-alpha-for-view-in-android)

i want to ask two questions:

1) i want to make the buttons in my `main.xml` i.e simply the first screen look semi-transparent.
It should be such that the background image can be partly-seen through it. But the button should maintain its normal size and looks.

2)(This is regarding another button in another view) i changed the background of buttons using

```
android:background="#2563EA"
```

but now when it is clicked it does not change its color. how can i reset it. also can anyone tell me how to give it a new `onClick` color.

Comment: There is already a thread about setting the alpha of buttons in Android here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757/how-to-set-opacity-alpha-for-view-in-android

Comment: If you want to ask two questions, **ask two questions**, don't put them both in **one** question =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the appearance of a button depending on state, use a [StateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the [alpha property](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color) for the transparency of the color. Also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757).
2. You can dynamically change the color by using the `OnTouch` event. Or better, you can assign the background in the XML to be a selector.

   ```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_pressed="true"
             android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
       <item android:state_focused="true"
             android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
   </selector>
   ```