# programmatically darken a View android

Tags: android

I found how to [change the opacity of a `View`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757/how-to-set-opacity-alpha-for-view-in-android), but I need to actually darken a `View`.  My best idea is to put a transparent black rectangle over it and then slowly increase the opacity of the rectangle.

Do you know a nicer way to do it?

```
public class Page07AnimationView extends ParentPageAnimationView {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private ImageView overlay;
    private int mAlpha = 0;

    public Page07AnimationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Page07AnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void init()
    {
        overlay = new ImageView(mContext);
        overlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.black_background);
        overlay.setAlpha(0);
        overlay.setWillNotDraw(false);
        // make the PageAniSurfaceView focusable so it can handle events
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    protected void draw_bitmaps(Canvas canvas)
    {
        overlay.draw(canvas);
        update_bitmaps();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void update_bitmaps()
    {
        if(mAlpha < 250)
        {
            mAlpha += 10;
            overlay.setAlpha(mAlpha);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above isn't doing what I had hoped.  `Page07AnimationView` is added to a `FrameLayout` over the view I need to darken.   `R.drawable.black_background` points to a 787px x 492px black png image.

I added `overlay.setWillNotDraw(false);` but it didn't help.
I changed the first `setAlpha(0)` to `setAlpha(255)` but that didn't help.
I removed the `setAlpha()` calls altogether, but it didn't help.

This basic technique of adding a `PageNNAnimationView` has been working to draw `Bitmaps`, but not to draw `ImageView overlay`.  (I would use `Bitmaps`, but they don't seem to have an alpha component.)

Edit2: this is the parent of the class above:

```
public class ParentPageAnimationView extends View {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    protected Context mContext;

    public ParentPageAnimationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public ParentPageAnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    protected void init()
    {
    }

    protected void draw_bitmaps(Canvas canvas)
    {
        // will be overridden by child classes
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(this.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        {
            if(canvas != null)
            {
                draw_bitmaps(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    public void update_bitmaps() 
    {
        // will be overridden by child classes
    }

    public void elementStarted(PageElement _pageElement) {
        // Nothing in parent class
    }

    public void elementFinished(PageElement mElement) {
        // Nothing in parent class
    }
}
```

Comment: I've confirmed that draw_bitmaps and update_bitmaps are being called repeatedly.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In case of an ImageView, here's one way to achieve it:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(123, 123, 123), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: does this use more or less resources then setting `.setAlpha((float)1.0)` (for sdk 11 and up) or `.setAlpha(100)` (for sdk 11 and under). The reason i ask is because im setting the opacity to achieve this, and if i can just call that and if its more compatible that would be great.

Comment: @AaronRussell i think that if you use setAlpha, it's better , since it might be GPU optimized. of course, i could be wrong on this. best thing should be to always use the newest API functions.

Answer (score 14):

I would rather do it in the opposite way - put a dark rectangle behind the view and set the view's opacity. This saves painting the rectangle when the view is 100% opaque.

Comment: this is a neat idea!  I think I'm constrained to doing something "over" the View though, by virtue of how I have my layouts laid out.  But having an animation layout *behind* them might solve another problem; thanks!

Comment: When running an animation behind a translucent view it may trigger repainting the entire screen. Enable "Show screen updates" in DevTools in the simulator and see what's repainted.

Answer (score 7):

I would do something like this:

```
view.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
```

Use black color with some alpha like `0x7f000000` for a typical darkening.

It's more concise and you can also darken the `View` with animation or scrolling event for example. Just set `Color.argb(alpha, 0, 0, 0)` as the color and animate `alpha`, or change it based on the scrolling offset.

Comment: This method is deprecated now, but you can set the color filter using a `ColorMatrixColorFilter` or `PorterDuffColorFilter`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I ended up doing it.  The key was to use a Paint with its alpha set to whatever I wanted.

```
public class Page07AnimationView extends ParentPageAnimationView {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private BitmapDrawable drawable;
    private ImageView overlay;
    private int which = -1;
    private long last_time;
    private Page07State state;
    private int mAlpha;
    private int maxAlpha;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private int _alpha_step;
    private int minAlpha;

    public enum Page07State {
        WAITING, DARKENING, DARKENED
    }

    public Page07AnimationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Page07AnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void init()
    {
        minAlpha = 0;
        mAlpha = minAlpha;
        _alpha_step = 5;
        maxAlpha = 255;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAlpha(minAlpha);
        state = Page07State.WAITING;
        overlay = new ImageView(mContext);
        overlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.black_background);
        drawable = (BitmapDrawable) overlay.getDrawable();
        bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        last_time = 0;
    }

    protected void draw_bitmaps(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if(state != Page07State.WAITING)
        {
            DebugLog.d(TAG, "drawing " + Integer.toString(which));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
        }
        update_bitmaps();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void update_bitmaps()
    {
        if(state == Page07State.DARKENING)
        {
            if(mAlpha < maxAlpha)
            {
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() > last_time + 12)
                {
                    last_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    mAlpha += _alpha_step;
                    mPaint.setAlpha(mAlpha);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                state = Page07State.DARKENED;
            }
        }
    }

    public void runAnimation()
    {
        state = Page07State.DARKENING;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to android developer's answer:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(123, 123, 123), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

you can setColorFilter on any view like this:

```
GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) textView.getBackground();
gd.setColor(color); //you can also set BG color to a textview like this
gd.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(123, 123, 123), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try using the Alpha animation like this (perhaps on the rectangle):

```
    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(350);
```

That would cause the rectangle to gradually become opaque over 350 seconds...

Comment: I think when he said *nicer* he meant "more proper", not "cuter"

Answer (score 1):

Android actually exposes a drawable which can be used to darken views. You can easily attach it to any view with an Overlay.

Here are two extension functions which can be used to darken any view.

```
fun View.darken() {
    val darkOverlay = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
            resources,
            android.R.drawable.screen_background_dark_transparent,
            context.theme
    )!!.mutate() // We mutate the drawable so we can later implement a fade in/out animation and animate the Drawable's alpha property. Since Drawables share their state we need to mutate otherwise we would impact all instances of this drawable
    darkOverlay.setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
    setTag(R.id.dark_overlay, darkOverlay)
    overlay.add(darkOverlay)
}

fun View.lighten() {
    (getTag(R.id.dark_overlay) as? Drawable)?.let {
        overlay.remove(it)
        setTag(R.id.dark_overlay, null)
    }
}
```

Make sure you add the id to `ids.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="dark_overlay" type="id" />
</resources>
```

And if you're darkening your application's root layout and would like to darken the `NavigationBar` as well, you *might* need to add the the following to your theme in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- required for api 29 otherwise the system will set a white background color to the NavigationBar to ensure the buttons are visible -->
    <item name="android:enforceNavigationBarContrast">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check iPaulPro's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow/3723654#3723654). You will need to extend `ImageView` and override the `onDraw()` method.

Depending on what you are going to do, Alexandru Cristescu's answer is also valid but you should 
call [setFillAter(true)](http://bit.ly/iNJIYm) for the animation to persist after finished.