# setAlpha for view programmatically

Tags: java, android

I saw in the Android documents there is a setAlpha API Level 1.I have a View that I try to use setAlpha(float) on the view, but the compiler says no such method exists.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757/how-to-set-opacity-alpha-for-view-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float) is only supported from API level 11 (not 1).

If you want to use this, you'll have to add to your Manifest something like

> `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"/>`

Comment: uses-sdk wont really address the issue. The calls to setAlpha() will fail in pre-11 devices

Comment: It depends on what the issue exactly is: if the OP wants to use setAlpha then he needs to set minSDK to 11. But as you point out correctly, that impacts the devices on which the code will run.

Comment: minSdkVersion is irrelevant, important is target=android-11 in project.properties

Answer (score 0):

Set the background of the view to a color using the ARGB scheme.

`android:background=#77777777` sets it to a dull translucent gray

This doesn't work in the case of ListView items, which is an exception.

Comment: Bad approach. Certainly for listview item it will mess with list selector.

Comment: @mice, the ListView is an edge-case, which my answer doesn't cover. I apologize.