# Android how to set opacity in bitmap xml

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, drawable, alpha-transparency

I need to create a bitmap resource via xml, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_home"
    >
</bitmap>
```

But I need to set opacity to this bitmap. Is there a way I can do this using this xml? I know that it would work if Shape tag was allowed inside of the bitmap tag, but I tried with no success.

Comment: I added android:alpha=".5" to the bitmap definition with no luck.  Anyone else been able to figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

If you’re displaying the Bitmap in an ImageView, you can probably use the `ImageView.setAlpha(int)` method. However, if the ImageView is accesed via RemoteViews, as is the case when updating a widget, you won’t be able to invoke this method (if you try to call it via `RemoteViews.setInt(int, String, int)` you’ll get an exception telling you as much).

```
 private Bitmap adjustOpacity(Bitmap bitmap, int opacity)
    {
        Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.isMutable()
                               ? bitmap
                               : bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
        int colour = (opacity & 0xFF) << 24;
        canvas.drawColor(colour, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
        return mutableBitmap;
    }
```

More [info](http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/01/12/adjusting-the-opacity-of-an-android-bitmap/). and most common just like you problem. [How to Set Opacity (Alpha) for View in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757/how-to-set-opacity-alpha-for-view-in-android)

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) of Bitmap from developer.android.com.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I would like to set the opacity in the xml, so I can use in a selector later.

Comment: @ComicSansMSLover: I have used `android:alpha="0.6"` in selector but its not working in APL level 20 and below. Did you get any way to do this?