# setAlpha(int a) not working when used inside a thread

Tags: android-animation, android

I am trying to change the view Alpha using setAlpha(int a) method, but it has no effect and also tried to perform alpha animation on same but the same result!. Please help.
Here is the part of code..

```
public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        myImage.setAlpha(1);
                    }
                });

        }
```

Comment: That method is deprecated. You should use setImageAlpha(int alpha) instead, though I don't know whether that solves the problem.

Comment: @DuneCat How did you come to the conclusion that it is deprecated? I see no mention of it at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)

Comment: @faizal It's not deprecated in View, but in ImageView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAlpha%28int%29

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know which values you've tried using, but the method takes values from 0 to 255, where 255 is completely opaque, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5153891/734079).

Comment: I figured out the same, 255 is opaque and 0 is transparent.anywz thx for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myImage.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
```

Comment: I think you mean setAlpha(255) ;)