# Android - How to Set a semi-transparent layout?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android application.  [image]

In this picture,there is a bottom layout with some options like play,delete etc.., and has its transparency to show its background.

How to I get like that ?

Comment: Brother,this is not ios UI .I took this from Google play store.

Comment: Play Store doesn't look like that on any Android device I've viewed it on. If it does, then the OEM gets a -1. Those are iOS buttons, every single one. Is it perhaps a Samsung device?

Comment: I don't remember which app it was .i just crop a screen shot of an app in play store.

Comment: So -1 to for whoever made that app then. I'm just saying, don't follow somebody else's bad design. Try to stick with the [Android Design patterns](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

use `android:background ="#88676767"` change the first *88* to your selection of opacity

In reply to your comment:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(your_imageId);    
iv.setColorFilter(Color.argb(150, 155, 155, 155),   Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

**Third option:**

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.relevant_drawable);
    d.setAlpha(50);
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Comment: yes I got your point. I set an Image for background to that layout like this android:background="@drawable/myimage" .Then How to give another attribute again for android:background ="#88676767".

Comment: I've added another option in the answer

Comment: Your use of `setAlpha` seems to be incorrect. It should be a value between 0 and 1 according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)

Comment: There are 2 setAlpha's: the (int alpha) one takes its parameter between 0 and 255. from the documentation: alpha The alpha (0..255) to apply to the view's drawing.

Comment: I am going to have to downvote this. This does not work fine. It gives me a gray background which has no semitransparency

Answer (score 17):

The color format is ARGB, which means ALPHA/RED/GREEN/BLUE.

The transparency is set on the alpha channel, a value of 0 (0x00) is completely transparent and a value of 255 (0xFF) is completely opaque.

So if you need a grayish color half transparent, then set this color: #80444444

Answer (score 6):

It's also incredibly easy to just set the alpha value, one of two ways. My example applies a 60% opaque black background to a linear layout.

The first method is to add the following line to change the alpha of the layout in the XML file (also in image):

```
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:alpha="0.6"
```

[image: XML File Method]

The second method is to change the alpha and background values in the design editor view:

[image: Design Editor Method]

Answer (score 3):

Refer these links:

[1.How to Set Opacity (Alpha) for View in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757/how-to-set-opacity-alpha-for-view-in-android)

[2. Android: how to create transparent or opeque background](http://zaman91.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/android-how-to-create-transparent-or-opeque-background/)

Answer (score 1):

Use 32-bit PNG with transparency for your background (in that particular case, cause it does not have uniform transparency)