# How to make any html color code semi transparent [Android]

Tags: android, color-codes

I have one Android application were i have one shape and in that i have one solid tag.

I want to make this shape 20% transparent with above color code.
How should i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-transparent-20-in-android

Comment: I think you are using Android Color code-
Color.Red etc?
So please use color code for that like-#452558
and in your circle use other color code which one is lighter than etc..

OR use setAlpha(200);

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the color is represented in hexadecimal, like #424242, then adding two more digits in front of this "number" will represent the transparency, ex: #66424242. (66 in this example)
You can play a bit until arrive at desired effect.

Comment: so this `AA` ranges from `0 to 255` also `66` is how many % of 100?

Comment: Well, you could convert the hexa digits to decimal, and then do a simple math to know what percentage of transparency represent that alfa value. In this case, 66 would represent about 40%.

Answer (score 3):

android:color="#66FF0000" is partially transparent red and if you decreasing the value of 6 as 5,4,3 up to 1 as "#56FF0000" ,"#46FF0000","#36FF0000","#26FF0000", the transparent color will becoming thin and the same way if u increase the first number as "#76FF0000","#86FF0000",
like that the transparent color becoming thick.so we can arrange the  transparency of color ourself. and it is applicable to all type of colors!!

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?

```
android:color="#66FF0000"    // Partially transparent red
```

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7689776/1391624

Answer (score 2):

I have tried adding two digits to the front of the 'number' e.g. #66424242, this definitely works since I use it on my blog