# Add a transparent overlay to a selected Imageview

Tags: android, selection, android-view, highlight, color-codes

How to add a **transparent overlay** to a selected `imageview`?

I have a recyclerview. The user can perform deletion by long pressing the items.
I want to highlight the items

What i did is this-

1) Along with the items i created a View and made it invisible         `android:visibility="invisible"` .
                 2) Made it visible if it selected in `onBindViewHolder()`

`viewHolder.overlay.setVisibility(isSelected(i) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);`

what i get is this

[image]

what i actually want is this, a transparent overlay

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a simple solution. This can be done using transparent hex code colors.

you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542775/how-to-make-any-html-color-code-semi-transparent-android).

so `View` in my xml is as follows

```
 <View
    android:id="@+id/selected_overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#7618AB8E"<!-- 76 for transparency -->
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
```