# Button opacity/transparency

Tags: android, xml, button, transparency, opacity

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:color="#66FF0000"

    >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/noua"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#808080"
         />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/zece"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#808080" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/unspe"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#808080" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/doispe"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#808080"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main.xml, I am trying to make the buttons the most transparent, but I want still to see them and I don't know what to add and where to add, please correct my xml with the low opacity on bottons. Premeditated thank you:D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

check [How to Set Opacity (Alpha) for View in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757/how-to-set-opacity-alpha-for-view-in-android)

You can set transparency on background of objects, use #XX808080, where XX is the alpha/transparency value.

```
android:background="#80FF0000"
```

this will be a half-transparent red background.

You can set transparency on the button text using the textColor property in the same manner:

```
android:textColor="#80FF0000"
```

You can also achieve through code in an animation

```
AlphaAnimation alphaAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.5f);
alphaAnim.setDuration (400);
myButton.getBackground().startAnimation(alphaAnim);  // set alpha on background
```

or directly:

```
myButton.getBackground().setAlpha(0.5f);   // added in API 11, sets alpha on background
```

both methods set the alpha to 50%

Lastly, you can try adding android:alpha for your XML:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/zece"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#808080" 
android:alpha="0.5"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably cant change its opacity with code, because they are 9patches. You need to create your own 9patch and set it to buttons as background. If you want a solid color, of course you can also use something like:

```
android:background="#80363636"
```

Here #AARRGGBB, how low you keep first two digits you get that opacity

Answer (score 1):

in code, you can get an instance of the button and set the background drawable's alpha manually.

```
 Button btn = (Button) findViewById(..);
 btn.getBackground().setAlpha( a );  // where a : 0..255 : 0=transparent, 255=fully opaque
```

Comment: I don't think you can set the alpha in the xml file.  There's no drawable resource that allows it [see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html ].  You'll have to either set the alpha in code or make your own semi-transparent background drawable and use that