# Blur input on edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, blur

I am creating an app for users to hold the phone in a specific way - therefore one method i am testing is blurring an image depending on the phones position.

Now I want to let the user do a small task - write something to an Edittext and blur the text too --- sure I could display the textinput as textview on top of the image, but probably the users eyes are focused to the edittext and not the image/textview

So is there a possibility to blur the input within the edittext? An other possiblity would be to blur the complete view (combined with a lot of refactoring), but I would prefer the edittext solution..

Would be great if someone would be able to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and use the alpha property of it to reduce the opacity.

A similar answer that makes a custom TextView for it can also be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904259/8118133

You can also look at adding a BlurMaskFilter if that does the job for you.

Comment: thanks the BlurmaskFilter was what I was looking for! Used this tutorial https://android--examples.blogspot.de/2015/11/how-to-use-blurmaskfilter-in-android.html