# Adjust toolbar opacity

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, toolbar, android-toolbar

Is there a way to adjust the opacity of the toolbar? I don't want to make it fully transparent, but tweak its opacity like 80% or 70%.

If it's possible, can you share some code please?

Comment: hi, no it doesn't because when i do it it just loses it's color tone. When i scroll, i can't see the text going behind the toolbar.

Comment: Even with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16535953/208273)? (in my opinion, the other, more upvoted answers are all wrong)

Answer (score 0):

if you use a color like #FF000000 as toolbar background(/tint),
then you can change opacity of it by changing FF to AA . (00 is fully transparent)