# can't dismiss popUpWindow

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

i created my popUp window

```
 public void myPopUp()
    {

        LinearLayout myView = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
         pw = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
         pw.setContentView(myView);
         myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
         pw.setWidth(curWidth-100);
         pw.setHeight(curHeight-100);
         pw.showAtLocation(background, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
   }
```

and overrided backButton pressed for dissmis

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            getNewWH();
               middle.removeView(bb);
            if(statusBG==2)
            {
                 log("statusBG = "+statusBG);
                 showFeed();
                 statusBG=1;
            }
            else
            if(statusBG==1)
                { 
                    finish();
                }
            else
            if (pw.isShowing()) {
                 log("here again");
                pw.dismiss();
                log("here");

            }
          return true;  
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

as u can understand me - i want dissmis/hide popupwindow  when i press on backButton but now i get folowing error's  :(

```
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259): Activity myClass.com.myClass has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer@44ec28a8 that was originally added here
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity myClass.com.myClass has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer@44ec28a8 that was originally added here
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:828)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:688)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at myClass.com.myClass.myPopUp(myClass.java:743)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at myClass.com.myClass$15.onClick(myClass.java:724)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-12 12:27:15.373: ERROR/WindowManager(1259):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can anyone help me  and tell how to correct dismis popup when i pressed on backButton ?

p.s. sorry for my bad english, hope u understand me . Regards, Peter.

Comment: same thing can be done using the dialog, try it ,it is easy to manage

Comment: i found solution here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121232/android-popup-window-dismissal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use getApplicationContext() instead pass context or this.

LinearLayout myView = new LinearLayout(context or this);

Comment: same thing can be done using the dialog, try it ,it is easy to manage

Answer (score 2):

For dismissing the PopupWIndow but not the root activity or view by backpress is to set the focus.
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

The popup window doesn't have focus so when pressing the back, it closes the main activity as the focus is on the main activity.