# onBackPress method is not fire when dialog box is open

Tags: android

I am follow this library for datetime picker https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker its working fine but if i am open the SingleDateAndTimePicker dialog and fire onBack press method then dialog box is close but am unable to go back  privous actvity and if dialog box is not open then onBack press code is fire any solution on that would be appreciated.
my code:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (singleDateAndTimePickerDialog!=null) {
        singleDateAndTimePickerDialog.dismiss();

    } else if (currentTime - lastPress > 5000) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press back again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        lastPress = currentTime;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: might be duplicate of [onbackpress event not firing when dialog is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655239/onbackpress-not-called-when-pop-up-window-is-displayed)

Comment: yamini if i am using finish() then activity also got closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

// a global variable
            private  SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog singleDateAndTimePickerDialog  = null;

```
        onCreate(){ 
        singleDateAndTimePickerDialog = new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog(this);
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onBackPressed() {

        if(singleDateAndTimePickerDialog != null 
        && singleDateAndTimePickerDialog.isDisplaying()){

                     singleDateAndTimePickerDialog.dismiss();
                     return;
                    }//if

                      super.onBackPressed();
                      finish();

                    }
```

==================================EDIT=====================================

You can use android DatePicker and TimePicker.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:calendarViewShown="true"
        android:spinnersShown="false"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/time_picker"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/date_time_set"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Set"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

..and android dialog.

```
final View dialogView = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.date_time_picker, null);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();

dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_time_set).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

         DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
         TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

         Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(),
                            datePicker.getMonth(),
                            datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
                            timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                            timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

         time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
         alertDialog.dismiss();
    }});
alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
alertDialog.show();
```

So you can do it like this:

```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {

   if(alertDialog != null  && alertDialog.isShowing()){

   alertDialog.dismiss();
   return;
   }//if

   super.onBackPressed();
   finish();

   }
```

Comment: questioner its close activity also any idea?

Comment: Do you want to close both the dialog and the activity, or just close the dialog, not activity

Comment: i want to close dialog box if dialog box is open the if we are press again back button then activity should be close like that.

Comment: in my case if dialog box is open then press back button the dialog box is close but if we are press again back button then activity not closed.

Comment: Ok can you try my answer? The current code is doing exactly what you're describing

Comment: isShowing() method is not working, and the result is same as per previous code.

Comment: questioner any solution on that or is i am doing something wrong on that?

Comment: I just implemented the library for you :D

Comment: in your case is working fine i mean isDisplaying() is cannot find symbol is there

Comment: is your version 1.2.0 ?

 compile 'com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:1.2.0'

Comment: i am using compile 'com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:1.2.2'

Comment: there was confusion because the variable names did not match, builder and dialog

Comment: qustioner thank for your support but its not working still.

Comment: change library :D singleDateAndTimePickerDialog mustn't private. It would be this way if it were public

Comment: questioner thank for reply i will check and let you know.

Comment: questioner  i think its a bug on library because i try the sample code also and after the close dialog box activity not get closed.

Comment: yeap you should change your library :)

Comment: in which version i need to change.

Comment: you need change

Comment: ok, can you suggest me any good date time picker library like that in  android

Comment: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=datetimepicker+android&type= :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try finishing the activity, once the dialog got dismissed.

```
 @Override public void onBackPressed() {
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (singleDateAndTimePickerDialog!=null) {
    singleDateAndTimePickerDialog.dismiss();
    finish(); // Or super.onBackPressed();
} else if (currentTime - lastPress > 5000) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press back again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    lastPress = currentTime;
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: mehul its closing activity also my code is working fine but its not fire if dialog box is open

Answer (score 0):

super.onBackPressed();

in else condition it's ok with your condition because in this condition onback not fire because super.onback in not proper condition.