# Dismiss Pop up window when back button is pressed

Tags: android, popupwindow

I want to dismiss the pop up window when back button is pressed. I tried with this code:
`popwindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());` and it works. But in my app, pop should remain, even after touching outside of the pop up window. It should be dismissed only when back button is pressed. So I tried this: `popwindow.setFocusable(false);`
Now its not dismissing when touched outside the pop up. But its not dismissing on back press too. I do not want to overide `onBackPressed(). Is there any other way, through which i can achieve this. Thanks in advance..

Comment: handle back press then

Comment: You may find solution in these links:
[1 Close Android popup window with back press][1]
[2 dismiss the popup window by back button][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940119/close-android-popup-window-with-back-press
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898723/dismiss-the-popup-window-by-back-button

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android popup window dismissal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121232/android-popup-window-dismissal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **disable pop up dismiss when click outside** of popwindow
set

```
popwindow.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

and **for dismiss it on back button**
set

```
popwindow.setCancelable(true);
```

Comment: But I'm not getting both properties. it's giving error as setCancelable cannot be resolved.

Comment: according to [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean)) this is not possible
"Sets whether this dialog is canceled when touched outside the window's bounds. If setting to true, the dialog is set to be cancelable if not already set."

Comment: But that is for the dialog. I'm using a pop up window

Comment: @SangeethaPinto  try this  pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);
pw.setTouchable(true);

Comment: If I add that, it dismisses when back button is pressed. But it also gets dismissed, when touched outside the pop up window. i dont want it to dismiss when touched outside the pop up window

Comment: Hi it worked by setting popUpWindow.setTouchable(false); thank you for helping me to find the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
new ScaleInAnimation(popupView).animate();
popupWindow.getContentView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
popupWindow.getContentView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @jinnings. it's help me to prevent closing popup when I back click.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, onBackPressed() is still called

Answer (score 2):

Set like this..

```
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true); 
    popupWindow.setTouchable(true); 
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());           popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() 
{ 
@Override 
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{ 
if (AppContext.isDebugMode()) 
Log.d("POPUP_WINDOW", "v: "+v.getTag() + " | event: "+event.getAction());
 popupWindow.dismiss(); return true; 
} 
});
```

Comment: setCancelable(true) will cancel pop window even on touching outside the window's bound

Comment: It will only cancel when you press back button or you touch outside of window dialog ..

Comment: SetCancelable(true) is applicable only for the dialog. I'm using pop up window

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but it worked by setting setTouchable(false);

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the `setOutsideTouchable(true)` and `setFocusable(true)` I had to add

```
popUpView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable())
```

to make it work. This did not change the UI of my popup, but for some magical reason, enabled the back button functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The code below may be helpfull:

```
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(mParent);
```

And,the show of the popupWindow (popupWindow.showAsDropDown or popupWindow.showAtLocation )must be called in the end.

Answer (score -2):

Set Popup property as..

```
      popup.setOutsideTouchable(false);
      popup.setCancelable(true);
```

Comment: But I'm not getting both properties. it's giving error as setCancelable cannot be resolved

Comment: according to [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean)) this is not possible "Sets whether this dialog is canceled when touched outside the window's bounds. If setting to true, the dialog is set to be cancelable if not already set."

Comment: Not worked first one & There is no such property popup.setCancelable()