# Android : handle touch event in nonTouchAble PopupWindow

Tags: android, view, touch, popupwindow

I'm working on joystick keyboard. I need create fullscreen popupWindow with View over 
third party application. My view on popupWindow will handle onTouchEvent, but then I need let this event continue to third party application. I'm calling popupWindow from service.

I've tryied to set return value of onTouchEvent (in view) to false, but without success...

This is my idea, but maybe there is another way...
I will be happy for any idea.

Thank you
Bruenor

Comment: i'm not sure about your problem, but 
[this][1]
does help me


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121232/android-popup-window-dismissal