# Why doesn't a PopupWindow whose layout is inflated from XML accept touch events?

Tags: android

Given a `PopupWindow` defined like this:

```
public class MyWindow extends PopupWindow implements View.OnTouchListener {
    MyWindow(View view) {
        super(view);

        setHeight(view.getMeasuredHeight());
        setFocusable(true);
        setTouchable(true);
        setTouchInterceptor(this);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("onTouch()");
        return true;
    }
}
```

for some reason, `onTouch()` is never called.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get the `PopupWindow` to accept touch events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3122696/1427098) to a different question, the `PopupWindow` needs to have a background `Drawable` explicitly set, even when it has been inflated from XML and doesn't visually need a background set.

I fixed this by adding this line:

```
        setBackgroundDrawable(new ShapeDrawable());
```

to the constructor.

Comment: Great, you solved a huge issue facing me, all the answers i found before were taking about setting the `BackgroundDrawable` as `new BitmapDrawable()` and this method is deprecated now and you are not allowed to set a `BitmapDrawable()` without defining `Resources` and an actual `Bitmap` or at least an `InputStream` that contains a `Bitmap`