# popupwindow's event method not fired

Tags: android

When I click on a thumbnail, a popup window opens. I want to dismiss it in the `onTouch` method but the problem is that the `onTouch` method is not getting called.So How can i get it run? How can I dismiss the popup window?

my code is:

```
public void onItemImageClicked(View view)
{
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)     getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup,null); 
    ImageView fullSizeImg = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.fullSizeImage);
    fullSizeImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    fullSizeImg.setFocusable(false);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int deviceWidth = display.getWidth()-40; 
    int deviceHeight = display.getHeight()-70; 
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, deviceWidth, deviceHeight, true);
    // display the popup in the center
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    popupWindow.getMaxAvailableHeight(new View(this));
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            return false;
        }
    });
    popupWindow.setTouchable(true);

}
```

Comment: Add this line popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable()); and check it will work.

Comment: i have added it before but it doesnt work.

Comment: add another  popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

Comment: i also have tried this and also put a methos showAsDropDown but it still not working

Comment: ok i worked on this and this this my working code http://pastebin.com/cMhKPwsc

Comment: Finally it's been solved... i was showing that popup before the listener code so it doesnt execute the onTouch event. but thank you very much for ur support.

Comment: Ok is my sample code work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
                View popupView = globalconstant.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
                popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,globalconstant.displayWidth-20,480,true);
                popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

And `onClickEvent`

```
popupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void initPopupWindow() {  
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  

View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_choice, null);  

ListView main_menu_listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_menu_listview);  

ShowMainChoice madapter = new ShowMainChoice(context);
main_menu_listview.setAdapter(madapter);

int width = (int)getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2;
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view, width,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());//this is important，如果缺少这句将导致其他任何控件及监听都得不到响应
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

main_menu_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.e("++++++>", arg2+"");

    }
});
```

}

> This problem is popupwindow底层的消息机制决定的，因为它是阻塞式的。
>   This is because the popup window does not respond to onTouch or onKey events unless it has a background that != null. Check out some code I wrote to help with this. In the basic case you can to call PopupWindow#setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable()) to force it to act the way you expect. You won't need your own onKey listener. You might also need to call PopupWindow#setOutsideTouchable(true) if you want it to go away when the user clicks outside of the window boundaries.

this is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121232/android-popup-window-dismissal) ,Good luck!