# How to avoid ghost click issue in android 2.3?

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am experiencing a strange behavior on my android device. When I click a button on my popup the underlying list element gets clicked. Any suggestions? I tried z-index approach.

Comment: there is no z-index in android

Comment: how do you handle the popup button click ?

Comment: Do you return true in your onClick method?

Comment: It's jquery mobile popup and am using phonegap. Should have specified.

Comment: Problem exist only in Android 2.3.

Comment: @Monerd Did you find a solution for this? Having the same issue. Frustrating as hell.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the popup window does not respond to onTouch or onKey events unless it has a background that != null.

The reason the background cannot be null is because of what happens in PopupWindow#preparePopup. If it detects background != null it creates an instance of PopupViewContainer and calls setBackgroundDrawable on that and puts your content view in it. PopupViewContainer is basically a FrameLayout that listens for touch events and the KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK event to dismiss the window. If background == null, it doesn't do any of that and just uses your content view. You can, as an alternative to depending on PopupWindow to handle that, extend your root ViewGroup to behave the way you want.

Make sure you call setBackgroundDrawable before showing the dialog... took me awhile to figure that one out.

I ran into a similar thing, found the answer I needed here:
[Android popup window dismissal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121232/android-popup-window-dismissal)