# PopupWindow does not dismiss on back key

Tags: android

In My Layout there is a EditText for search and there is a list below the EditText.Now I'm inflating this layout in a PopupWindow .
Now My problem is

1)If I set the PopupWindow focusable true , then all the places other than the PopupWindow  Layout becomes non clickable.So I can not dismiss the window by clicking outside or by clicking on the back button of the device

2)If I set the PopupWindow focusable false , then the Popupwindow open and close is perfect but soft keyboard is not becoming visible on tap of the EditText

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
mPopUpWindow= new PopupWindow(layout,0, mScreenHeight - 100, false);
mPopUpWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
mPopUpWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
mPopUpWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                        mPopUpWindow.dismiss();

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

final InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager) MainApplication.getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMgr.showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {

inputMgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Could you please paste some code here, so we can see where the problem might be or give you a hint on how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
View popupView= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popupmenu,null);
                PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
                popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                popup.showAsDropDown(view);
                popup.update();
```

The main point is that `PopUpWindow` can't be null. See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3122696/1979347)

Answer (score 0):

Add the three lines in the code:

```
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(ivmainmenu);
```

And,the show of the popupWindow must be called in the end.