# How to dismiss PopupWindow when clicked outside?

Tags: android

In one of my activity, there is a `button`, which when clicked opens a `PopupWindow`.
My intention is, when the PopupWindow is opened and user clicks anywhere on screen except the popup area, the PopupWindow should be dismissed.

For this I have set:

```
// onClick()
myPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
myPopupWindow.setFocusable(false);
```

Issue is it works fine & PopupWindow gets dismissed when I click anywhere outside, but if I click on the button that generated this PopupWindow, then that event is consumed and PopupWindow first gets closed and then gets opened again.

I tried moving my button `onclick()` code to `onTouch()`. 
But if I `return true`, then button consumes every event & opens popup again and again, even with slightest drag while touching the screen.
If I `return false`, it behaves same as in onClick() & opens the popup again when button is touches back.

**So how can I dismiss the PopupWindow even when clicked on the button?**

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/3122696/957654

Answer (score 2):

Just disable that button after it has been clicked so that it can't be clicked when the pop-up window is displaying. `button.setEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem as follows:

```
      settingsImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!settingsMenu.isShowing()) {
                settingsMenu.showAsDropDown(settingsImageButton);
                settingsImageButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
    settingsMenu.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    settingsImageButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }.execute();
        }
    });
```

I call the method setEnabled() asynchronously, because onDismiss event is earlier than onClick event.