# Closing a PopupWindow with the back button?

Tags: android

I've got a popupWindow that I'm using to display google maps but once it's open I can't seem to close it, I'm trying to set the back button to close it but can't call the onBackButtonClick override as I'm inside a fragment. Doesn't seem to do anything though

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_go, container, false);
    mRouteBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.routeBtn);

    mRouteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            View popupView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null);

            mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            // If the PopupWindow should be focusable
            mPopupWindow.setFocusable(true);
            mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.routeBtn), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            mPopupWindow.update(0, 0, 800, 800); //don't hardcode
```

Back button code part:

```
            mPopupWindow.getContentView().setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event ){
                    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ){
                        mPopupWindow.dismiss();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            } );
        }
    });
```

Alright sorted, after following **Deepak Singh's** advice I got it working although when I reopened it I had issues with crashing due to trying to recreate a view that still exists. here's my working code for future reference:

**FIXED VERSION:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_go, container, false);

    mRouteBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.routeBtn);

    mRouteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mPopupView != null) {
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mPopupView.getParent();
                if (parent != null)
                    parent.removeView(mPopupView);
            }
            try {
                mPopupView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null);
            } catch (InflateException e) {
                /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
            }
            mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(mPopupView,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
            mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.routeBtn), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            mPopupWindow.update(0, 0, 800, 800); //don't hardcode

            mPopupView.findViewById(R.id.doneBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mPopupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you post back button code ?

Comment: As you are inside a fragment, I would suggest adding a DialogFragment using getChildFragmentManager() instead.

Comment: have you try to use : setOutsideTouchable(true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a button on your pop up window layout and find the id of button using `popupView.findviewbyid(id)`,then set **clicklisener** on this button and call  `mPopupWindow.dismiss()`;.

Also you can try this:

```
 popupView.setOutsideTouchable(true);
 popupView.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: Yeah .This logic is simple

Comment: That's working great however now when I reopen the popup it crashes with Duplicate id.

Answer (score 0):

add to your code `popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);`

Comment: Tried that, didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: If the popup is showing, calling this method will take effect only the next time the popup is shown or through a manual call to one of the update() methods.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3122696/2838869) you need to set a background drawable to the popup window.

I tested it out and you don't even need to handle the `OnKeyListener` by yourself.

This should be enough to make 'back button' work:

```
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```