# PopupMenu counter not show

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, popupmenu

I want to show notification counter like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlsFf.jpg]

But instead of a counter on `NavigationView` as shown in the image, I want it to shown in `PopupMenu` at *pending_req* item

Here is *menu_project.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:title="@string/detail" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/pending_req"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
            android:title="@string/pending_request"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>
    </group>

</menu>
```

Here is a method to show `PopupMenu`

```
private void showProjectMenu(View v) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_project, popupMenu.getMenu());

    TextView pendReqN = (TextView)popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.pending_req).getActionView();
    pendReqN.setText("3");

    popupMenu.show();
}
```

EDIT:
And this is the result when click item *00004*
[image]

What I want
[image]

How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You need Custom View List using `RecycleView` which has one icon,text and the number textview as per your requirement

Here is on [Example](https://github.com/rudsonlive/Navigation-Drawer-ActionBarCompat)

You can refer this example

Comment: Could you please provide more details about Custom View List. Replace MenuItem with Recycle View?

Comment: In my application, icon is not necessary but thank you for the example. Let  me take a look at the example.

Comment: In the given example, the listview is fixed. But I dont know how to implement a thing like PopupMenu using ListView. I search on Google and mostly found the implementaion of PopupMenu when click on the ListView item.

Comment: I added a wider screenshot of what I have done so it may give you more idea of what I'm doing.

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: I dont know how to implement a thing like PopupMenu using ListView.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320781/android-custom-popup-menu-with-switch