# Having trouble with PopupWindow

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-2.2-froyo

I'm just starting to go through tutorials for writing Android apps.  My first app is hopefully going to be very simple, but I am having a little trouble with the next step.  I have my main GUI working, which is a simple `LinearLayout` with several Buttons arranged vertically.  When I click on the Connect button, I want a PopupWindow to appear, with the following information:

```
TextView: "Enter IP Address"
EditText: <ip address should get entered here>
Button:   "OK" --> connects to a PC listening for requests
```

The problem is, when the PopupWindow is created, I can barely make out any of the text in the TextView, but it's definitely there.  More strangely, I can't see the EditText or the Button.  It's almost as if the PopupWindow is fading into view, but gets frozen partway.

I used the code from [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967863/is-there-a-simple-example-of-the-popupwindow-class-using-android-v2-0) for getting the PopupWindow to (kind of) work.

Once the PopupWindow (kind of) displays, my app is frozen because it's obscuring the main GUI at that point.

I have also added calls to showAsDropDown() and dismiss(), and when I do this the PopupWindow definitely disappears because I regain responsiveness in my main GUI.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Here's what I am talking about regarding the barely-visible TextView:

[image]

Comment: use this in manifest file---><activity android:name=".name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>

Comment: @Piyush: thanks, but that changes my main app to look like a dialog.  I want my app to be full screen and just display a popup when I click Connect.  I am going to post a picture to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it absolutely have to be a `PopupWindow`?  Would a custom `Dialog` do instead?  You can specify your own layout & buttons etc.  Some examples using custom dialogs are [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), [here](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/02/create-custom-dialog.html) and [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example/).

Comment: After looking over several posts, that seems to be the right thing to do -- use a Dialog instead of a PopupWindow.  I'm going to give it a shot.  Thanks!