# How does a popup window on Android work if needed in non-Activity class?

Tags: android, android-activity, popupwindow

I am having an issue with creating a pop-up window. I have a game i'm developing, and I'm trying to have a window or sub-menu pop up after I've won the game so the user has an option of quitting or restarting. Everything I've seen on popup windows is done in the activity. I want to do this from my "controller" class, basically I want to check to see if the user has won within my logic class and if they did bring up a window, I have a feeling, I'm going to have to do this in my activity. Any help would be appreciated it. If you need any further details just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do it in the Activity. You have two options:

1) When you know the game is over, have a method in your "controller" class that returns whether or not the popup should be displayed. Something like isGameWon(). Call this from your Activity and respond accordingly.

2) Keep a reference to your Activity in your controller class, or allow access to your Activity as a singleton object. When the game ends, check if the player won in your controller class, and if so, call a function in your Activity to display the popup, like showGameWonPopup().

You can't display a popup outside of the UI Activity. Your two classes need to communicate about the end result of the game and respond accordingly.

Comment: Ah, yea I actually had planned to do your first option, just wanted to see if I could just do it straight from non-Activity class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can show a popup from a custom non-activity class.  I do it from a custom class that is set as the onTouchListener for a button in my activity.  The key in this case is to get the parent of the view that is passed into the onTouch method from the activity.  I think you can access the popup container view for an arbitrary class by passing your constructor the underlying activity (or the layout you used for setContentView() in that activity).

```
public class CustomListener implements View.OnTouchListener{

    public PopupWindow mPopup;

    public TalkButtonListener(Context ctx) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            ctx.getSystemService(ctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mPopup = new PopupWindow(
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null, false), 
            100,100,true);
    }

    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event){

        View v2 = (View) v.getParent();

        switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mPopup.showAtLocation(v2, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            return(false);
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mPopup.dismiss();
            return(false);
        default:
            return(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to Todd for the code on showing the popup ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967886/1109396)).