# How to instantiate PopupWindow?

Tags: android

I'm looking at [APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) and have absolutely no idea how to create and show the `PopupWindow`. Why are the APIs are written in such a way that people need to search for other resources in order to understand how to use a particular thing?

Well, anyway, can you please describe how can I create and show `PopupWindow`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967863/is-there-a-simple-example-of-the-popupwindow-class-using-android-v2-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the APIs is to provide technical documentation. Their primary purpose is as a reference material, not as a learning tool. That said you can learn a lot from reading them.  In general I find that googleing for  *tutorial* tends to get me started in the right direction.  There are lots of examples of PopupWindows in android, check out this StackOverflow post: [Is there a simple example of the PopupWindow class using Android v2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967863/is-there-a-simple-example-of-the-popupwindow-class-using-android-v2-0)