# How to create popup modal window in android

Tags: android-layout, android, popupwindow

I am trying to create a popup window for android honeycomb like google docs application  I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967863) tutorial, I am able to get popup, but how to make it as modal window? How to create border effects like the one shown in image

[image: Screen shot of popup window]

Comment: That must be one of [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) flavors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.

```
 Dialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(Buddies.this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT)
                    .setTitle("Create New")
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .setItems(new String[]{"Document", "SpreadSheet","",""}, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int position) 
                        {
                            if ( position == 0 )
                            {   
                            }
                            else if(position == 1){

                            }
                            else if(position == 2){


                            }

                        }
                    })
                    .create();
                    d.show();
```