# creating a popup like this

Tags: android, user-interface, twitter

How to make a popup like in the image when we click a link and what it is known as?

[image: loading failed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve that if you use a [PopUpWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) and set the backgound to be bubble like that in the picture you are showing in your question. See [the answer of this previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967886/1482726) for a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this implementation:

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

It just a popwindow. Take a look here. It will explain you clearly.

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-apps/quick-action-demo/