# PopupWindow does not pop up

Tags: java, android, android-popupwindow

I am trying to set PopupWindow in my app and it does not pop up.

Here is my code:

```
popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
                popUp.update(50, 50, 300, 200);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                tv.setText("Hi this is a sample text for popup window");
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                params= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);          
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                layout.addView(tv,params);
                layout.addView(cl);
                layout.addView(stats);
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                main.findViewById(R.layout.ajax);
                mainLayout.addView(check,params);                   
                popUp.setContentView(layout);
                // popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
                setContentView(mainLayout);
```

What do I need to do to get this work and get a PopupWindow?

Thank You.

Comment: You may want to consider using AlertDialog(.Builder). See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: I tried the AlertDialog but I need the PopupWindow that is perfect for my app. can you help me setting the PopupWindow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967863/is-there-a-simple-example-of-the-popupwindow-class-using-android-v2-0

Comment: I am trying what you gave me in the link but "this.getSystem.Service" does not exist... what should I do?

Comment: this is my code now: `inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     popUp=new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null,false),100,100,true);
     popUp.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.layout.ajax), Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);`  but it still doesn't work. (R.layout.ajax is the xml of the Activity and R.layout.popup is the xml for the popup).

Comment: Does your layout.popup render in the visual form designer?

Comment: Try implementing the example in that question and only then slowly modify it to finally end up with what you want. That way you'll know where the issue lies

Comment: Do I need to initialize the context when I write `context.get...`? if yes to what? `Context context=null;`?

Comment: context == your activity

Comment: I tried coding it in other project and I am getting error about the context (the same code with the changes to the project). "context cannot be resolved"

Comment: It would seem you are very new to Android development. I will say again: don't try to instantiate context. Use either your activity or your service as the context variable for any function calls that require context.

Comment: I can't fix it. my code: `TVajax.setText(show);  TVajax.setTextColor(Color.RED);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)      Ajax.this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
           inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null, false), 
100,100,true);      pw.showAtLocation(Ajax.this.findViewById(R.layout.ajax), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); ` the first 2 lines work,the other not working.

Comment: What's Ajax.this.context supposed to mean? Where is this function of yours? Again: context == activity, so unless you use fragments, just use getSystemService / findViewById, without Ajax.this.context.

Comment: ok now I have the same code without the `Ajax.this.context.` but still the PopupWindow not displayed in my app.