# AlertDialog to wrap it's content

Tags: android, layout, android-alertdialog

I have a custom `View` which I use for my `AlertDialog`'s title and content, here's the view:

view_tip.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/StandardLinearLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:maxWidth="245sp"
        android:id="@+id/actionTip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I want `AlertDialog` to wrap it's contents. I've been following solutions from this thread: [AlertDialog with custom view: Resize to wrap the view's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907104/alertdialog-with-custom-view-resize-to-wrap-the-views-content) but none of them works for me.

Solution 1, no effect at all, `AlertDialog` takes the whole space:

```
// Scala code
val title = getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_tip, null)
title.findViewById(R.id.actionTip).asInstanceOf[TextView] setText "title"

val view = getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_tip, null)
view.findViewById(R.id.actionTip).asInstanceOf[TextView] setText "content"

val dialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this).setCustomTitle(title).setView(view).show
dialog.getWindow.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

[image]

Solution 2 which uses `forceWrapContent` to modify a view hierarchy, has an effect on content but the title is unaffected:

```
// Scala code
val title = getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_tip, null)
title.findViewById(R.id.actionTip).asInstanceOf[TextView] setText "title"

val view = getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_tip, null)
view.findViewById(R.id.actionTip).asInstanceOf[TextView] setText "content"

val dialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this).setCustomTitle(title).setView(view).show
forceWrapContent(title)
forceWrapContent(view)

...
// Java code
static void forceWrapContent(View v) {
        // Start with the provided view
        View current = v;

        // Travel up the tree until fail, modifying the LayoutParams
        do {
            // Get the parent
            ViewParent parent = current.getParent();

            // Check if the parent exists
            if (parent != null) {
                // Get the view
                try {
                    current = (View) parent;
                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                    // This will happen when at the top view, it cannot be cast to a View
                    break;
                }

                // Modify the layout
                current.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            }
        } while (current.getParent() != null);

        // Request a layout to be re-done
        current.requestLayout();
    }
```

[image]

Are there any other solutions or can I somehow modify the existing ones to make them work?

Answer (score 6):

You can use **custom Dialog instead AlertDialog**.

Here is example of **Custom Dialog**

```
    custom_dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth);
    custom_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable((0xff000000)));
    custom_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    custom_dialog.setCancelable(false);
    custom_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_layout);
    custom_dialog.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    custom_dialog.show();
```

If above logic not works you can use [Android Popup Window](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). It can be used to display an arbitrary view, and it can be very convenient in cases when you want to display additional information.

### How do i create PopupWindow

Create custom popup xml for contain

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Pop-Up"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java code:**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
   this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
   inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_example, null, false), 
   100, 
   100, 
   true);
// The code below assumes that the root container has an id called 'main'
pw.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

[Code Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967863/is-there-a-simple-example-of-the-popupwindow-class-using-android-v2-0).

For Demo purpose you may check Git [AlertDialogPro](https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro) And [CustomAlertDialog](https://github.com/holmeszyx/CustomAlertDialog) .I hope it will helps you .

Answer (score 1):

use window manager

```
private WindowManager wm;
wm = (WindowManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
params1 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
params1.height = (height/3);
params1.width = width;
params1.x = 0;
params1.y = 0;
params1.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
ly1 = new LinearLayout(arg0.getApplicationContext());
ly1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
ly1.addView(hiddenInfo);
wm.addView(ly1, params1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This here looks like your first solution but it's little bit different - maybe it works written like that - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406804/how-to-control-the-width-and-height-of-default-alert-dialog-in-android/4447618#4447618)

If this don't work you can create your own Dialog class which uses **popuWindow** - if you want i can show you some of my code to get you started.