# How to implement view/interface like this in android?

Tags: android

[image]

If i click on(+Add to group)Button then alert/Dialog like view should visible. How to implement view like this in android??

Comment: make the whole red border layout in Framelayout & make visibility Gone & when you want visibility visible it will come in front

Comment: use PopupWindow for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be simply implemented using [android-popupwindow](/questions/tagged/android-popupwindow).

Examples:

- http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-popup-window-in-android/28285
- [Is there a simple example of the PopupWindow class using Android v2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967863/is-there-a-simple-example-of-the-popupwindow-class-using-android-v2-0)

**Basic Steps:**

1. Create a layout in XML for the menu.
2. Inflate that layout and apply to the `PopupWindow`.
3. Acquire a reference to that button. (i.e. Add to Groups);
4. [Find its absolute coordination on the window.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view)
5. Use `showAtLocation` to show the menu in the appropriate location.

**Note:** AFAIK, there's a bunch of libraries out there which fit your requirements. So, don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

It's doable. You have to manually create a custom layout that automatically gets dismissed after pressing the action item.

Here is a small android library to create the QuickAction dialog style:

[QuickAction Library](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D/blob/master/readme.md)

For more info, read [this article](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/).